# JSPWiki pages on a different disk

Tags: tomcat, debian, arch

**My *JSPWiki* servlet on *Tomcat* cannot make use of a wiki page directory not located in *tomcat/lib*** as it did before. Any idea why?

I am using JSPWiki 2.11.3 and Tomcat 10.1.6.
In *jspwiki-custom.properties* I have specified

```
jspwiki.fileSystemProvider.pageDir = /home/rsc/share/tomcat/lib/jw
```

where */home/rsc/share* is a mount point of a different disk. *Tomcat* itself is install at */opt/tomcat* without modifications.

Access rights should be ok: The *tomcat* user is in the group of the symbolic link and the wiki pages directory. Group members have **r**ead and **w**rite access and **x** access for folders, recursively.

When I copy the wiki pages folder over to *tomcat/lib* and change the *jspwiki-custom.properties* accordingly, *JSPWiki* works as expected.

I have the same configuration running on a different VM. I compared all configuration files: they are equal.

The differences are:
It works as expected on **Debian 11 / Tomcat 10.1.4**.
With the same *Tomcat* and *JSPWiki* configuration it makes problems on **Arch manjaro / Tomcat 10.1.6**.

[Here](https://owncloud.august.de/index.php/s/RI1wlAiP7rIbCTh/download) you can find the *Tomcat* log.

Comment: trying to narrow the problem i came to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1770723/group-access-to-a-vbox-shared-exfat-file) question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do not put a mount point below a users home directory.**

I moved the mount point of VBox shared folder from `/home/rsc/share` to `/home/share`. That way the *tomcat* user is not restricted by the access permissions of the *rsc* users home directory.

Why this situation works in *Debian 11* would need further investigation.